# Why assembly character print can return

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

The following code prints the character 'a':

```
mov dl, ‘a'
mov ah, 2
int 21h
```

I've read [this manual](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html) and found that in `al` we get:

> Return: AL = last character output

What I am trying understand is *why* do we actually need this sort of return value?It makes no sense to me as we get the output on screen, and we have the last printed character anyway in DL (as we just printed that). Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ralph Brown's interrupt list says:

> AL = last character output (**despite the official docs which state
>   nothing is returned**) (at least **DOS 2.1-7.0**)

"Nothing is returned" does not mean: "The values of the registers are not changed" but this may mean: "The values of the registers may have any value."

Maybe MS-DOS versions 2.1 to 7.0 internally use the `AL` register in a way that `AL` *normally* contains the character written when the interrupt returns.

However because the official MS-DOS documentation says that nothing is returned you cannot rely on that:

Under some circumstances some MS-DOS version may return any other value in `AL`!